# Why 600MB of "BrowserMetrics"?

Tags: chromium, disk-usage, cleanup

In `./chromium/common/chromium/BrowserMetrics`, I find over 100 files named like `BrowserMetrics-60B60603-3D7326.pma`, collectively over 600MB, all dating to the past ~5 days.

[That's in addition to `./chromium/common/chromium/Default/Cache`]

What are those and can I get rid of them?

Chromium 91.0.4472.77 snap on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (5.8.0-53-generic)

Answer (score 3):

Also found in

```
.config/google-chrome/BrowserMetrics
/home/$USER/snap/brave/115/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/BrowserMetrics
```

so it is something generic. [Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Browser_Metrics) has a definition on what is does:

> Goals & Objectives In order to understand how people use the browser
> and to evaluate our efforts to improve the browser, we need to collect
> and analyze usage data. There are many types of data that can be
> collected, such as:
>
> - Session history navigation (to understand navigation patterns and
>   improve the tab/window UI as well as backend features like bfcache) UI
>   elements (which widgets are and aren't being used)
> - Cache effectiveness (hit rate, bloat, etc)
> - Memory usage (to understand how memory usage changes during normal navigation)
> - Unsupported content (to understand how many people are affected and prioritize projects accordingly) "Problems" (unhandled exceptions in browser chrome, assertion failures)

[Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96817?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) has something similar.

---

Disable/enable:

- Open Chrome/Chromium, More, Settings.
- Under "You and Google" select "Sync and Google services".
- Turn on or off "Help improve Chrome's features and performance"

[image]

Mozilla/Firefox has it under "Sync" and "Firefox data collection and usage".

[image]

I am unsure if old cache files are removed if you disable it. You probably also need to empty cache (also found at settings).

Comment: In chromium I have "Make searches and browsing better" ([img](https://i.ibb.co/306LK54/2021-06-05-22-16-36.png)), but I've disabled it long ago. And my default search engine is duckduckgo.